# React Stateful Class Component: using "this.setState" to update properties of the state, not working. No error. State doesn't change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state, lifecycle

I know there are several questions covering this, but they didn't help me. I basically have this:

```
state: {
  location: 'Tahiti',
  price: ['2000'],
  day: {August}
  
}

componentDidMount() {
    const updatedprice = '1800'
    this.setState({price: updatedprice})
}
```

I've done more or less the same for the other properties, except for price where I tried to set an object as the new state. This has always worked for me, and is working elsewhere. What is going wrong? Any pointers?

All of the component is basically this. I just wanted to play with modifying the state.

PS I did a console.log on when I'm setting the state: this.setState({price: updatedprice}), and it gives undefined, this happens with other properties too.
Although, I have no errors, it's simply that when I console.log the state, it shows zero difference.

Comment: Your description seems a little thin. Can you provide more context? (Also, this might not fix your problem, but your initial value for `price` is an `Array`, while your updated value is a `String`.)

Comment: Thank you for chiming in! This was just an abstraction. I didn't include my entire code because it's over 20 properties and I've basically tried to update several with different values, just like above. The this.setState is all taking place inside a componentDidMount, and I've tried writing a function for setting the state and then calling it inside the component. Whether the new property value is the same type or not, it always returns the old value for that state property. I did a console.log on when I'm setting the state: this.setState({price: updatedprice}), and it gives undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You just have the syntax wrong.

```js
this.setState({price: updatedprice});
```

Comment: Thank you for that catch! I don't know why I wrote it that way here, I should have copy and pasted. It's actually correct inside of my application.